# Set default compiler for linking C code in Python package

Tags: python, compiler-construction

I'm trying to compile a Python package which has some Cython-generated C code, and I'm running into:

```
gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
```

which indicates that the gcc compiler is too recent, so doesn't support -arch anymore. I tried setting `CC=/usr/bin/gcc` prior to `python setup.py install`, and this works for the main compile command, but not for the command to make the shared object library:

```
% setenv CC /usr/bin/gcc
% python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'hyperion/util/integrate_core.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'hyperion.util.integrate_core' extension
/usr/bin/gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/include/python2.7 -c hyperion/util/integrate_core.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/hyperion/util/integrate_core.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -g -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/hyperion/util/integrate_core.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/hyperion/util/integrate_core.so

gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
gcc: error: unrecognized option ‘-arch’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Is there a way to specify the absolute path of the compiler to use for linking?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LDSHARED` variable: `LDSHARED='/usr/bin/gcc -shared'`.

It's buried in `sysconfig` module. Try this:

```
>>> from sysconfig import get_config_vars
>>> get_config_vars('CC', 'CXX', 'LDSHARED')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like so:

`CXX="/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.0" CC="/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0" python setup.py build`

but I'm not sure that's "right"; it's  just part of a long command I need to use when installing scipy/numpy.

(full command I end up using is 
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/ FFLAGS="-m64" CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/  -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/X11/include -L/usr/X11/lib"  LDFLAGS="-Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle  -lpng -arch x86_64" CXX="/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.0" CC="/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0" python setup.py build`)